# Error "Warning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I solve this error?

> Warning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
> _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))

The error appears when I add Adam's tuning parameter.

```
# Tuning parameter from keras.optimizers import Adam
optimize = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.99)
model.compile(optimizer=optimize, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What is the error of this code?

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

prediksi = model.predict(test_data_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(prediksi, axis=1)
print(confusion_matrix(test_data_generator.classes, y_pred))
print(classification_report(test_data_generator.classes, y_pred))
```

I've also tried using `labels=np.unique(y_pred)`, but the results do not show the value of the **accuracy** of.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll notice that it's not actually an error, but a warning. It also doesn't happen ini the `Adam` line, but rather in the `classification_report` line -- this is because the classification report computes F1.

Answer (score 9):

This warning occurs because `y_true` contains labels that are not present in your predictions (`y_pred`) like in the example below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

y_pred = np.ones(10,)
y_true = np.ones(10,)
y_true[0]=0
print(confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_true,y_pred))
```

You can remove this warning by setting `classification_report` argument`zero_division=1`.

But it is not wise as it shows you that there is a problem with your classifier.

Answer (score 0):

You should know:

- When `true positive + false positive == 0`, precision is undefined.
- When `true positive + false negative == 0`, recall is undefined.

In such cases, by default the metric will be set to 0, as will f-score, and `UndefinedMetricWarning` will be raised. This behavior can be modified with `zero_division`.

- Detail on https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14876

And now you can change the behaviour by `zero_division`:

> ```
> zero_division : string or int, default="warn"
>     Sets the behavior when there is a zero division. If set to
>     ("warn"|0)/1, returns 0/1 when both precision and recall are zero
> ```